# Storing Formatted Text for SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that contains a footer.   The footer is formatted text with bold, italic, carriage returns and indentation.  The footer also changes based on the account the report is ran for, so I cannot hard code the footer into my report.  What is the best way to store this text so that I can query the contents and past it into a text box in my report.

I have tried SQL but that seemed like it would get messy fast because I'm not sure how to format HTML or MarkUp in the SSRS Textbox. The HTML just gets pasted in as text.  My other idea is to store the formatted text in an excel sheet but I am not sure if that is best practice either and I'd rather store it in something more secure if possible.

[image]

Edit: I have tried the HTML and it seems to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<body>
<p><b>Compliance Rules*:</b></p>
<p>

        <b><div style="text-indent: 1in">Info 1: 10% of capital commitments</div>
        <div style="text-indent: 1in">Info 2: 10% of capital commitments</div>
        <div style="text-indent: 1in">Info 3: 15% of capital commitments</div></b>

</p>

<p><b>*This list is not exhaustive of all guideline restrictions or limits that may apply</b></p>
<p><b><i>Duration calculation does not take into account sinking provisions for securities with sink features.</i></b></p>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: SSRS will let you use some HTML tags. The HTML needs to be enabled by highlighting then right-clicking on the Expression --> Placeholder Properties and change the Markup Type to `HTML`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/importing-html-into-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Another option is to use placeholders. You can add individual placeholders within a single textbox. These can either be fixed text or can be value from your dataset as normal. Each placeholder can be set wit its own formatting. I'm not sure if this would be suitable as it's not clear from your question which parts, if any are fixed and which are dynamic. You can add placeholders by clicking inside a text box to get a cursor then right-clicking inside the textbox and selecting 'add placeholder'

Comment: @AlanSchofield ahh sorry yes, it is a bit unclear.  The entire text box will be dynamic.  I just hard coded an example value for this screen shot.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, so @HannoverFist 's comment is your best bet.

Comment: Keep in mind the word "some" in @HannoverFist's post.  SSRS supports a pretty thin set of html tags, so if you're going to be using much more than basic text formatting, you may want to pursue another solution.  If it's just text formatting, then HannoverFist's solution is the proper one to use.

Comment: @FrankBall The HTML almost works.  I am having trouble using the text-indent style which microsoft documentation says SSRS supports.